# How can I create an array of buttons in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view containing 80 `UIButton`s, and 80 `UIImage`s. Rather than refer to these by individual outlet references, I would like to refer to them as indexes in an array, and so be able to change the Image, and work out which `UIButton` is sending a message without specific references.

I am sure this must be possible, as there is no way having 80 different versions of the same code is correct way to do this!

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a UICollectionView?

Comment: make array of buttons

Comment: Go for `UICollectionView`. will be more appropriate for this

Comment: how does the view looks like.. all elements vertically/horizontally or like a grid where you will show images and buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be better served by looking into `UICollectionView`, but to answer the question as asked:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i = i + 1) {
        // However you wish to get your button
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, i * 20, 20, 10);
        [self.view addSubview:button];
        // Other button-specific stuff (like setting the image, etc.)
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.buttonArray addObject:button];
    }
}
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    int index = [self.buttonArray indexOfObject:sender];
    // Now handle the button press based
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, it’s called outlet collection.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutletCollection NSArray *buttonsArray;
```

Comment: It looks like from what I'm seeing that you need to manually set the type of the objects contained in the array. In your case, you could use `UIButton` if they're all going to be buttons, but you could also use `id` for a diverse collection. Something like this: `@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonsArray;` From the little testing I've done with it, it looks like it will put them in the array in the order that you hook them up in IB (so the first button you connect will be at index 0, the second at index 1, etc).